# Failure to upload document: Access denied

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am using SharePoint Online Communication site and while i am trying to upload custom page templates i could not upload them and the migration tool says "Failure to upload document: Access denied."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue occureses when the customization are made to a "Group team site" or a "Communication site" witch are "Modern sites".

In that case a additionnal step is requared, witch is "enable customize scripts using PowerShell".

Here's PowerShell for you.

```
#Parameters
$TenantAdminURL= "https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com"
$SiteURL= "your site collection URL"

#Connect to Tenant Admin
Connect-PnPOnline $TenantAdminURL -UseWebLogin

#Get the Tenant Site Object
$Site = Get-PnPTenantSite -Url $SiteURL

#Enable Custom Scripting by turning OFF Deny Flag
$Site.DenyAddAndCustomizePages = "Disabled"
$Site.Update()
$Site.Context.ExecuteQuery()
```

Reference:

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/12/how-to-enable-custom-script-in-sharepoint-online.html#ixzz6Y0ZOWt61